Howland circuit gain factor
I do not understand how the gain of the Howland circuit can be derived on an operational amplifier. I am attaching a photo of the circuit 

Here are two excellent descriptions of the circuit. The second one is from National Semiconductor's grand wizard, Robert Pease. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/the-howland-current-pump/ https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa474a/snoa474a.pdf

Your question is very interesting and relevant. But apart from the expression, you should also understand the idea of ​​this famous circuit. And it is brilliantly simple...

@AnalogKid, Could you share with us (in one or two sentences) what is the great idea of ​​this circuit that you understood from the excellent TI material? We will be very grateful for your enlightenment…

Not sure what you mean by "great idea".  The core idea of its conception?  The most significant uses?  Its influence on other designs?  Please clarify.

@AnalogKid, the first...

This circuit seems to be an "improved" Howland circuit.
Here is how it should be "solved" ... Maple sheet.
The current I solved is the current in R2 resistor.
Note how R5 and RH are used ...
You can note also that current is "constant", whatever the value of R2 is.


I add also a microcap v12 simulation with the variable RH is used ...
X2 is an opamp buffer, gain = 1.
Same calculus as before, with different values of resistors, output variable changed.


How can I use formulas to deduce Uout/Uin?

I must add in maple sheet ... I will do asap. ... Done.

The voltage across R5 is VR5 = -Vвх.R3/R1. So, the load current Iвых flowing through R5 and accordingly, through Rн, is Iвых = VR5/R5 = - Vвх.R3/R1/R5.
If R1 = R2 = R3 = R4, Iвых = -Vвх/R5.
Brilliant as the Howland's idea...
